# Cannot Resolve @style/Theme.Sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to make use of Actionbar Sherlock 4, targeting sdk 15 and min sdk 8. After following the directions provided on the Usage website and the great videos posted here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcp6eD_X2k

I'm still encountering a problem. When I try to add android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" to my manifest file , I get the error:

> No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value
>   '@style/Theme.Sherlock').

I have included the actionbar Sherlock library project into my project, and the import statements are there and not coming up with any errors and I've

> extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener

just like in the Demo code and documentation Yet still, eclipse gives me this error. Any ideas out there?

Comment: Are you using eclipse? Did you mark the Actionbar Sherlock as an android library?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I encountered a strange anomaly that might help!

Have built android project that uses ABS, running it on Gingerbread works fine, in ICS it crashes, the crash under ICS occurs due to this, check your *AndroidManifest.xml* (have trimmed out bits for brevity...

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock">
```

It was the ***android:theme*** part that caused the crash under ICS, it worked fine under Gingerbread and older versions!. Solution was to remove it completely! Then from your Activity, do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
        this.setTheme(com.actionbarsherlock.R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
   }
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   ... // MORE CODE ....
}
```

This fixed up the crash under ICS, the theme style is not liked by ICS, but it works fine for both versions less than 2.3 and 4.0 upwards.. weird error but that I discovered by fluke!

Remember to apply the theme before calling the base class's own *onCreate*!

Comment: This should not be necessary. I have used ActionBarSherlock in many sample applications on everything from Android 2.1 to 4.0.3 with the style defined in `<application>` with no ill effects. While your approach *may* work *currently*, I would not rely upon that -- if you are using `SherlockActivity` or kin, you really should use the correct theme.

Comment: I beg to differ, that *is* the correct theme used in ABS... just saying and it is the latest and greatest version used.

Comment: This is wrong. `Theme.Sherlock` (and its variants) can be used on all API levels. If it crashes on ICS then it is for a different reason.

Comment: @Roylee You'd need to do a project clean & recompile the source ;)

Comment: @t0mm13b do you have experienced in getting github android or bitcoin wallet to work on eclipse? is it possible to hand me some guide? Because I have tried maven but yield no result, wonder if i did wrongly.

Answer (score 16):

The pitfall I encountered was this: The reference to the ActionBarSherlock project needs to be in the Android->Libraries section of the project properties, while I had been adding it to the Build Path->Libraries.

Comment: this answer saved me from pain

Answer (score 4):

My standard procedure for including a library project on Eclipse goes like this:

- Import library project
- Right click on library project Properties -> Android -> Set Project Build Target (insure library and primary project are the same)
- Right click on library project Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties
- Select the library project then Project -> Clean...
- Select primary project then Project -> Clean...

That should fix whatever ails you.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. Unfortunately this trick didn't solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the solution:

1. IMPORTANT! Copy the same android-support-v4.jar in both projects: in library and your project (this is the principal problem).
2. Import "library" project TO YOUR WORKSPACE
3. Right click on library project Properties -> Android -> Check "Target Name" 4.x (any, API level 14,15 or 16). Bottom check "Is library".
4. In properties, go to "Java Build Path", tab "Libraries" And find "android-support-v4.jar" normally in "Android Dependencies". Ok and Close Properties.
5. Right click on library project Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties
6. in Menu Project -> Clean... and select to clean the "Library" Project.

In this place, your project "library" must to be done (without errors)

1. Create or import your own project. Example "MyProject"
2. In properties, go to "Java Build Path", tab "Libraries" And find "android-support-v4.jar" normally in "Android Dependencies".
3. Now go to "Projects" Tab. Add... and select "library" project.
4. Now in properties go to Android -> Check "Target Name" 4.x (any, API level 14,15 or 16). IMPORTANT: Must to be the same of "library" project. Bottom "Is Library" must to be UNCHECKED and in this place press Add... And select "library" project. Ok and Close properties.
5. Right click on "MyProject" project Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties
6. in Menu Project -> Clean... and select to clean the "MyProject" Project.

Already, your project must to be done. If the error persist, restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by the follwoing 2 steps on my projects:

1. Remove the "library" from "project properties"/build path and add library in "project properties"/Android/Library
2. Right Click on project "Android Tools" -> "Add support library"

Answer (score 1):

after importing both projects i.e. library and settingActivity,first clean and build them.
Then right click on  settingActivity project->properties->select second option from left menu (i.e android).
on right hand side their is library section just click on add library. prper path will automatically comes in that frame.
Thats solve my problem,i got no errors.